# how to rewrite footer in the custom plugin Reaction Commerce

Tags: reaction-commerce

Right now, I am using [Reaction Commerce](https://www.reactioncommerce.com/) 1.10. I would like to create a custom plugin and rewrite the footer but have no idea how to do that.

Here is the footer code:

```
import React from "react";
import { registerComponent } from "/imports/plugins/core/components/lib";

const Footer = () => (
  <div className="reaction-navigation-footer footer-default">
    <nav className="navbar-bottom">
      <div className="row">
        {/* Footer content */}
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
);

registerComponent("Footer", Footer);

export default Footer;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do that by first creating your custom plugin:

`reaction plugins create --name your-footer-plugin`

Then, create a `components` directory under `/imports/plugins/custom/your-footer-plugin/client`.

In `/imports/plugins/custom/your-footer-plugin/client/components`, create a `Footer.jsx` file.

In this file, use the Component API to replace the `Footer` component with the component you'd like:

```js
import React from "react";
import { replaceComponent } from "@reactioncommerce/reaction-components";

const Footer = () => (
  <footer>
    <p>This is your new, custom footer.</p>
  </footer>
);

replaceComponent("Footer", Footer);
```

Finally, make sure that you create an `index.js` files in `/imports/plugins/custom/your-footer-plugin/client/components` to import your component:

`import "./Footer";`

And another `index.js` in `/imports/plugins/custom/your-footer-plugin/client` to import your `component` directory's index:

`import "./components";`

Make sure that you restart Reaction with `reaction reset -n && reaction` for these changes to take effect.

Comment: Thank you very much for all these detail information. Just one thing, I think I should import the original footer into the Footer.jsx first. Otherwise, I got some error message.

Comment: There shouldn't be a need to import the default Footer component. What error are you getting?

Comment: I am sorry. It was my mistake. The error message is not for the Footer component. Your code works perfectly. Thank you~